# Assign button from another class to a current class selector with cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I instantiate a class and then I try to change the selector of the instantiated class button:

```
WebViewController *newtab = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigatorNoBottom" bundle:nil];
[[newtab tabsButton]setAction:@selector(addtabs:)];
```

The button `tabsbutton` is an outlet of the WebViewController class which is directly linked in interface builder. 
The method `-(void)Addtabs:(id)sender` is a method in my current class.

But it seems that this code does not work, my button is here but it does nothing when I click on it .

If you need more context don't hesitate. I know this is something maybe very simple but I just bug at it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `-initWithNibName:bundle:` does not load the nib file immediately. This means that right after sending it you cannot expect your outlets to be set.

In that line where you send `-setAction:`, your `tabsButton` outlet is probably `nil`.

If  `WebViewController` inherits from `NSViewController`, you can place that line that sets the action in the `-loadView` method of your `WebViewController` class to make sure the nib file has been loaded and all outlets are set:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    [tabsButton setAction:@selector(addtabs:)];
    // or [self.tabsButton setAction:@selector(addtabs:)]; 
}
```

Alternatively, if you don’t want to do this inside the view controller, you can do the following in an arbitrary class:

```
WebViewController *newtab = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigatorNoBottom"
    bundle:nil];
[newtab view];
[[newtab tabsButton]setAction:@selector(addtabs:)];
```

By sending `-view` to the view controller, you force it to load the nib file, hence the `tabsButton` outlet will have been set right after that.

Note that you can set the action in any class since a selector is not tied to a class. Also note that, since you haven’t set a target, the action will follow the action chain.

Comment: I've corrected my code with something like yours, the real problem was the target ! It works perfectly now, thank you very much !